# UITextField doesn't work in my SecondViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a big noob problem. I new in `iOS` and I'm trying to do this:

I have two `ViewControllers`. The first one has an button that if it is pushed, control goes to a second view controller.

That works but the problem is when I try to get data in my second view controller. The `UITextfield` doesn't work.

I'm trying to display which I insert into textfield in the label. But THE TEXTFIELD DOESN'T WORK :(

I putted the IBOutlets succesfully in the xibs and connect the buttons with their IBActions...

This is my code:

ViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@class SecondViewController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) SecondViewController *secondViewController;

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize secondViewController;

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:self.secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

SecondViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
    UIButton *obtener;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *obtener;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

-(IBAction)obtenerClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
    #import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize obtener, textField, label;

-(IBAction)obtenerClicked:(id)sender {
    label.text = textField.text;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: You mean text value is not setting in your label??

Comment: I writte "something" in the textfield. Then i push the button, and the label continue empty. So, the program dont work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SecondViewController.h, add this property:

```
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) NSString* myString;
```

now in firstViewController's onClick method, add this line

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

//....... Previous code....
 self.secondViewController.myString= @"String to be sent";
}
```

This will pass the string for you..

if you want to pass the string in text field, use this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    //....... Previous code....
     self.secondViewController.textField.text= @"String to be sent";
    }
```

hope it will work fine for your requirement.

**UPDATE:**
Do the following to get expected results:
1. make your secondViewController a textView delegate.

in your secondViewController.h
replace `@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController` with `@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>`

1. put a button in your secondViewController & create an IBAction for it.
2. on Click event of button, write this:

   self.label.text= self.textfield.text;

tell me if it does not work.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for answer me. But it is not my problem.

I dont want to send data between viewcontrollers. I want set the textfield in the second view controller and with the IBAction set the label.

Your solution is for sent data to textfield, i want that an user put himself.

Comment: @Eladar Are you getting a keyboard when tapping on textField?

Comment: Im using the keyboard of the simulator and i tryed too with my real keyboard, but is the same, the problem persists.

Comment: @Eladar.. So, when you are typing from keyboard, r u seeing some text appearing in the textField?

Comment: Yeah, but when i push the button, the label doesnt set with the text.

Comment: @Eladar.. can u show what u did. or can you share/send me the code?

Comment: Maybe im doing something wrong. Im trying to make an app with 2 view controllers. The ViewController A has buttons, textfields etc that works into him. The View Controller B has buttons textfield etc that work into him too. This is how i know to do it, maybe exist another method to do it.

Comment: did u fix the problem?

Comment: I sent an email to achievelimitless@gmail.com

Comment: @Eladar.. There is nothing wrong in code.. just the button was not linked with IBAction. once see the IBAction method of "obtainer" button. You can see an empty circle on left side. It means, UIButton is not connected. Just connect it by ctrl+drag & its working perfectly.. :)

Comment: @Eladar.. Sent you modified code..Feel free to accept the answer if it helped ..:)